# How do I make a hotkey on Numpad0, but make Numpad0 work as before?

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote this code:

```
Numpad0::
{
    Loop
    {
        Send {Numpad0}
        Sleep, 10
        if !GetKeyState("Numpad0", "P")
            break
    }
    return
}

Numpad0 & Numpad1::
{
    Send {Volume_Down 1}
    return
}

Numpad0 & Numpad2::
{
    Send {Volume_Up 1}
    return
}
```

It works. But if you press Numpad0 and hold it, it will write only one character. It should be a loop. Why does the loop not work?

Program version: 1.1.33.11.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. I tried something like this once years ago, just to see repeat rate. Maybe try?:

```
~Numpad0::
While (getKeyState("Numpad0", "P") {
    Send, {Numpad0}
}
```

Not sure why that would be different, but the tilde allows pass through of the hotkey to the active window instead of just capturing it like usual.